# How to host Spring Boot Application on Web Hosting Server

Tags: java, web-hosting

I know this question might sound stupid but for me it's new. I have developed a simple Spring Boot Application, provide some backend APIs, running on localhost. I have also bought an webhosting server with my own domain, let's say: `www.my-domain.com`. Right now in the `my-domain.com` I just have some simple html code. And what I want to do is having the spring boot application running also under this domain.

Is it possible then? If yes can anyone point me to some references please?. If no, what do I need to run an Java Application under my own domain?

Thank you very much!

Comment: we need to know more about your hosting service. Most hosting services that I know of are mainly working with PHP. Cheaper solutions usually can't even do anything else than that. You should look for ways to start an application server, like Tomcat, or WebLogic, that can run Java code and serve requests to that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the Spring boot application on the server, then you need to configure your web server (nginx/apache), configure Spring API path and port on the web server, and the traffic will go into your application.